# Problem about python writing files with accents or foreign signs

Tags: python-3.x

I was making some python tests when I started having some problems with python writing files. I wanted to make a basic script that reads the code of a .py file and writes this code in a .txt file, adding an annotation at the beginning  of it, but when this code has any foreign letter, like "ñ" or "á", it writes "�" instead. I'd appreciate any help.
Here's my code:

```
a = "ñ, á"
data = open("AutoscriptTest.py", "r", encoding="utf8")
lines = data.readlines()
lines[lines.index('a = "ñ, á"\n')] = '#Test\na = "ñ, á"\n'
data = open("AutoscriptTest.txt", "a")
data.writelines(lines)
```

And here's my text file:

```
#Test
a = "�, �"
data = open("AutoscriptTest.py", "r", encoding="utf8")
lines = data.readlines()
lines[lines.index('a = "�, �"\n')] = '#Test\na = "�, �"\n'
data = open("AutoscriptTest.text", "a")
data.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Your `open` line tells Python that file **is** saved as an UTF8 encoded file. Is that true?

Comment: yeah, I've already solved my problem. I forgot to add the utf8 encoding in the second opening.